# Trouble converting a snippet of LESS to SASS

Tags: css, sass, less

I've used the less2sass npm to convert some LESS to SASS and I have a couple sections that aren't converting correctly and raising error during SASS compilation.

The original less looks like:

```
.btn-default {
     #gradient > .vertical(@start-color: @gradient-default-start;
    @end-color: @gradient-default-end
    );
}
```

The converted SASS looks like this:

```
.btn-default {
     #gradient > @include vertical($start-color: $gradient-default-start;
    $end-color: $gradient-default-end
    );
}
```

I'm not familiar enough with LESS to understand what's happening.  Help please?!

Comment: Does not work.  Error: Invalid CSS after "... > .vertical > ": expected "{", was "@include gradie..."

Comment: The complete statement would probably be something as `@include gradient-vertical($gradient-default-end, $gradient-default-end);` (Well, I was assuming you have at least *some* knowledge of Sass).

Comment: I did include the error message. And the full line currently in my scss file is as follows: `#gradient > .vertical > @include gradient-vertical($gradient-default-start, $gradient-default-end);`, which produces the same error: Invalid CSS after "... > .vertical > ": expected "{", was "@include gradie..."

Comment: You understand you're using a `;` after your `$gradient-default-start`, when a `,` would probably solve this.  Right?

Comment: Doh, no! `#gradient > .vertical` -> `@include gradient-vertical` means `#gradient > .vertical` should be converted to `@include gradient-vertical`. (`->` is a shortcut for "to be replaced with").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SASS (SCSS)you could write the following code:

```
// Vertical gradient, from top to bottom
//
// Creates two color stops, start and end, by specifying a color and position for each color stop.
// Color stops are not available in IE9 and below.
@mixin gradient-vertical($start-color: #555, $end-color: #333, $start-percent: 0%, $end-percent: 100%) {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, $start-color $start-percent, $end-color $end-percent);  // Safari 5.1-6, Chrome 10+
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, $start-color $start-percent, $end-color $end-percent);  // Opera 12
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, $start-color $start-percent, $end-color $end-percent); // Standard, IE10, Firefox 16+, Opera 12.10+, Safari 7+, Chrome 26+
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#{ie-hex-str($start-color)}', endColorstr='#{ie-hex-str($end-color)}', GradientType=0); // IE9 and down
}

$gradient-default-start: red;
$gradient-default-end: green;

.btn-default {
@include gradient-vertical($start-color: $gradient-default-start, $end-color: $gradient-default-end);
}
```

the above SCSS code will output CSS code like that shown below:

```
.btn-default {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, red 0%, green 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, red 0%, green 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, red 0%, green 100%);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FFFF0000', endColorstr='#FF008000', GradientType=0); }
```

The Vertical gradient in the above had been copied from the [Official Sass port of Bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass).

Your original Less code uses `#gradient > .vertical()` which means that the `.vertical()` mixin has been [namespaced](http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-namespaces-and-accessors). To use that code in SCSS you have to rewrite it to a 'normal' mixin first, so remove the `#gradient` wrapping of `.vertical()` and than you can call the mixin as any other mixin.

Comment: Thank you Bass.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  Not only did you answer the question, you explained why it was a problem in the first place.  Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

In Sass, you can't include mixins inline in selectors. If you want to nest the result of the `vertical` mixin within `#gradient >`, you can do so explicitly:

```
.btn-default {
  #gradient > {
    @include vertical($start-color: $gradient-default-start,
                      $end-color: $gradient-default-end);
  }
}
```

You can make this a little terser by combining the two selectors:

```
.btn-default #gradient > {
  @include vertical($start-color: $gradient-default-start,
                    $end-color: $gradient-default-end);
}
```